# Why does this java code return no output?

Tags: java

This is a question on a quiz. The question asks what output is given when this code is ran. I don't understand why nothing gets output. Can someone explain? My understanding of the if/else is that if the if statement fails the else statement runs. Why doesn't the else statement run?

The code:

```
int age = 10;
char registered = 'n';

if(age >= 18) {
    if(registered == 'y') {
    System.out.println("You can vote!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("You're not old enough");}
}
```

Comment: It's on the end of the second-to-last line

Comment: because `age` is no greater than 18?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because this is you *actual* code (indented correctly):

```
if (age >= 18) {
    if (registered == 'y') {
        System.out.println("You can vote!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You're not old enough");
    }
}
```

`age` is less than `18` so nothing in the outermost `if`-statement gets executed.

(I think this is a terrible quiz question, to be honest. It's nothing more than trickery with brackets -- it doesn't really test your knowledge of Java.)

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code correctly and you'll realise that nothing happens if `age < 18`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable age has the value 10, then the it does not satisfy the first if condition if(age >= 18), and all the rest of the code is inside the true-branch of this condition.